# How can I automatically respond to system prompts in an R script?

Tags: r

I am conducting a methylation age acceleration analysis using an R script provided by MorganLevineLab ([GitHub](https://github.com/MorganLevineLab/PC-Clocks)).

There are two system prompts that require me to input certain answers when executing this script. However, since my data is extensive, it would be challenging for me to closely monitor the program. Hence, I am wondering if there are any tips available to **automatically provide answers for the two system prompts when they appear**.

Below are the relevant sections of the script that require input:

```
# Get the PC Clocks values and the PC Clock Acceleration values
PCClock_DNAmAge <- calcPCClocks(path_to_PCClocks_directory = clocksDir,
                                     datMeth = datMeth,
                                     datPheno = datPheno)
#in order to calculate Acceleration below, you will need a column called "Age", just as was needed for PCGrimAge.
PCClock_DNAmAge1 <- calcPCClocks_Accel(PCClock_DNAmAge)
```

When executing the *"calcPCClocks"* function, I intend to provide the input **"SampleID"** for the system prompt. Furthermore, when another prompt arises while the *"calcPCClocks_Accel"* function is running, I plan to respond with **"No"**.  Below is what I will do when responding by myself:

```
> PCClock_DNAmAge <- calcPCClocks(path_to_PCClocks_directory = clocksDir,
+                                      datMeth = datMeth,
+                                      datPheno = datPheno)
To check whether datMeth and datPheno match up, type the column name in datPheno with sample names (or type skip): *SampleID*
```

```
> PCClock_DNAmAge1 <- calcPCClocks_Accel(PCClock_DNAmAge)
Do you want all of the GrimAge Components? (yes/no) *No*
```

I would be grateful if someone could assist me in automatically responding to the prompts using R commands. Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to modify the two functions so that instead of requesting the information from the user, they take the same information from a parameter that you populate when calling the function.  Since you've not provided us with the source of the function nor the type of values you need to supply, it's impossible to give you a precise guidance on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Limey, I used the concept provided in your answer and tried to modify the scripts, it works very well now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: As the lingo goes,  "TRWTF" here is whoever wrote this script demanding user inputs.  That's almost always a **VeryBadDesign(TM)** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment above...

Suppose you have a function like this:

```
originalFunction <- function() {
  num1 <- as.integer(readline("Give me a number: "))
  num2 <- as.integer(readline("Give me another number: "))
  print(paste0( num1, " plus " , num2, " is ", num1 + num2))
}
```

It works manually:

```
> originalFunction()
Give me a number: 1
Give me another number: 2
[1] "1 plus 2 is 3"
```

But you could rewrite it like this:

```
newFunction <- function(num1, num2) {
  paste0( num1, " plus " , num2, " is ", num1 + num2)
}

newFunction(1, 2)
[1] "1 plus 2 is 3"
```

which means you can do things like:

```
set.seed(123)
lapply(
  1:4, 
  function(x) newFunction(sample(1:10, 1), sample(11:20, 1))
)
[[1]]
[1] "3 plus 13 is 16"

[[2]]
[1] "10 plus 12 is 22"

[[3]]
[1] "6 plus 15 is 21"

[[4]]
[1] "4 plus 16 is 20"
```